# Реализация алгоритма "cапёр" с помощью структур

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры, struct

```
int main()
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    Game board;
    Player player;
    board.CreateBoard();
    board.ShowBoard();
    Position pos;
    pos.coordX = 2;
    pos.coordY = 2;
    player.Shot(pos);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h

```
#include "time.h"

struct Game
{
    int coordXmax = 10; //минимально по координате X
    int coordYmax = 10; //минимально по координате Y
    int minAmountBomb = 10; // минимально бомб

    Cell *board;

    void CreateBoard();
    void ShowBoard();
    void MineTheField(); // Заминировать
    Cell GetCell(Position pos); // возвращает клетку
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <ctime>

void Game::CreateBoard()
{
    int counter = 0;
    board = new Cell[coordXmax * coordYmax]{};
    for (int i = 1; i <= coordYmax; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= coordXmax; ++j)
        {
            Cell cell;
            cell.pos.coordY = i;
            cell.pos.coordX = j;
            cell.countBomb = 0;
            cell.symbol = '#';
            cell.isBoomb = false;
            cell.isOpen = false;
            board[counter++] = cell;
        }
    }
    MineTheField();
}
void Game::MineTheField() // Заминировать 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < minAmountBomb; ++i)
    {
        int randCell = rand() % 100;
        board[randCell].isBoomb = true;
    }
}
void Game::ShowBoard()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= coordYmax; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= coordXmax; ++j)
        {
            /*if (board[counter].isBoomb)
            {
            board[counter].symbol = '0';
            printf("%c ", board[counter].symbol);
            }
            else*/
            printf("%c ", board[counter].symbol);
            counter++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
Cell Game::GetCell(Position pos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (coordXmax & coordYmax); ++i)
    {
        if (board[i].pos.coordX == pos.coordX && board[i].pos.coordY == pos.coordY)
        {
            return board[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

struct Player 
{
    void Shot(Position pos);
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Cell.h"
void Player::Shot(Position pos)
{
    Game game;
    Cell cell = game.GetCell(pos);
    cell.CheckAround(cell);
}
```

Cell.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Position.h"
struct Cell
{
    Position pos;
    int countBomb;
    bool isBoomb;
    bool isOpen;
    char symbol;

    bool CheckAround(Cell cell);
};
```

Cell.cpp

```
#include "Cell.h"
#include "Game.h"

bool Cell::CheckAround(Cell cell)
{
    if ((cell.pos.coordX > 0) && (cell.pos.coordX <= 10))
    {
        if ((cell.pos.coordY > 0) && (cell.pos.coordY <= 10))
        {
            if (!cell.isOpen)
            {
                cell.isOpen = true;
                cell.symbol = '.';
                if (!cell.isBoomb)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Помогите правильно реализовать `struct Cell`. Идея в том, что бы когда пользователь делал выстрел по `player.shot(2,2)`, проверялась эта ячейка, вокруг себя и последующие. Массивами понимаю, а как это реализовать с помощью структур не могу разобраться.

---

P.S. Реально ли сделать без рекурсии?

Comment: В таком случае (если не хотите использовать массив), вам нужен какой-то строитель, который создаст сцену из взаимосвязанных клеток. Тобишь каждая клетка должна иметь указатели на, какбы, соседние клетки (или nullptr), если таковых нет. Организацией этих взаимосвязей и должен заняться строитель.

Comment: Теоретическое понимание вами сказанного у меня есть, но как это реализовать не до конца ясно

Comment: что вам не ясно?

Comment: сделать двумерным массивом просто и не составляет труда, а вот как сделать это с массивом клеток, не получается реализовать открытие пустых ячеек